# What is the simplest login access control method for a jquery mobile application that Safari iOS can remember the username and password?

Tags: jquery-mobile, jquery-plugins, access-control, login-control

I tried using htpasswd but Safari on iOS does not allow for remembering of username and password.

Is there a script somewhere that may be of use?  Or do I need to set up a mysql database.

the username:password@mysite.com solution is not ideal unfortunately.

Comment: Are you using jquery mobile in cordova or on browser?

Comment: I'm using the web browser